# How tot get back from numpy datetime array to datetime?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

tried to write a simple programme for get the most vacation between two dates. E.g. for 2021, if wednesday is public holiday, you could get 9 free days with taking 4 holidays.

..everything okay, my idea was:

create busdaycalender, start, end, arange it and count all free days in a bool array and return the days.

Now my problem:

How could i get back the format for datetime?!I wanted to substract day2 from day1 (if day2-day1 > 1 and < 5 there is a holiday in between)
I tried to convert all "-" in ",", but the problem ist the zero at 2021-08-11 in front of e.g. the 8.
Here's my code. Maybe someone has an idea.
thanks !!

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

start = dt.date( 2021, 1, 1 )
end = dt.date(2021,12,31)


bdd = np.busdaycalendar(weekmask='1111100',
            holidays=['2021-01-01', # 1.Januar
                      '2021-01-06', # 3 Könige
                      '2021-04-02', # Karfreitag
                      '2021-04-13', # Ostermontag
                      '2021-05-01', # Tag der Arbeit
                      '2021-05-21', # Vatertag
                      '2021-06-01', # Pfingstmontag
                      '2021-06-11', # Fronleichnam
                      '2021-10-03', # Tag der deutschen Einheit
                      '2021-11-01', # Allerheiligen
                      '2021-12-25', # 1. Weihnachtsfeiertag
                      '2021-12-25']) # 2.Weihnachtsfeiertag
#print(bdd.holidays)

days = np.busday_count(start, end, busdaycal=bdd)
#print(days)
alldays = np.arange('2020-12-31', '2022-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')
#print(alldays)

def count_urlaub2(numbers):
    results = []
    tage = []
    counter = 0
    for number in numbers:
        if np.is_busday(number, busdaycal=bdd) == bool(False):
            counter += 1
            tage.append(np.datetime_as_string(number, timezone='UTC'))
        elif (np.is_busday(number, busdaycal=bdd) == bool(True)) and counter:
            counter = 0
    return tage

neueliste=[]
for i in count_urlaub2(alldays):
    a = i.replace("-",",")
    neueliste.append(repr(a))
print(neueliste)

positionen = []
for k in neueliste:
    for l in neueliste[1:]:
        erg = dt.date(l) - dt.date(k)
        if erg.days > 1:
            positionen.append(blabla.index(k))
            print("evtl Urlaub nehmen")
```

Comment: could you clarify: you want to get a list of datetime objects from a numpy array of dtype datetime64? In this case you could e.g. use astype; `arr.astype(datetime)` with `dateime` being the datetime class you import from the datetime module.

Comment: `blabla` is not defined anywhere. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: @MrFuppes - yes, that's the way i did it now. THX!

Comment: @OctaveL - it was just n example list for printing. Forget the line.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that clear to me, but if the issue is with `dt.date()` not working, this is what you're looking for.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

start = dt.date(2021, 1, 1)
end = dt.date(2021, 12, 31)

bdd = np.busdaycalendar(weekmask='1111100',
                        holidays=['2021-01-01',  # 1.Januar
                                  '2021-01-06',  # 3 Könige
                                  '2021-04-02',  # Karfreitag
                                  '2021-04-13',  # Ostermontag
                                  '2021-05-01',  # Tag der Arbeit
                                  '2021-05-21',  # Vatertag
                                  '2021-06-01',  # Pfingstmontag
                                  '2021-06-11',  # Fronleichnam
                                  '2021-10-03',  # Tag der deutschen Einheit
                                  '2021-11-01',  # Allerheiligen
                                  '2021-12-25',  # 1. Weihnachtsfeiertag
                                  '2021-12-25'])  # 2.Weihnachtsfeiertag


days = np.busday_count(start, end, busdaycal=bdd)
alldays = np.arange('2020-12-31', '2022-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')


def count_urlaub2(numbers):
    tage = []
    counter = 0
    for number in numbers:
        if not np.is_busday(number, busdaycal=bdd):
            counter += 1
            tage.append(np.datetime_as_string(number, timezone='UTC'))
        elif np.is_busday(number, busdaycal=bdd) and counter:
            counter = 0
    return tage


neueliste = []
for i in count_urlaub2(alldays):
    neueliste.append(i)
print(neueliste)


positionen = []
for k in neueliste:
    for l in neueliste[1:]:
        erg = dt.date(*[int(a) for a in l.split('-')]) - dt.date(*[int(a) for a in k.split('-')])
        if erg.days > 1:
            positionen.append(blabla.index(k))
            print("evtl Urlaub nehmen")
```

The most important line being `erg = dt.date.fromisoformat(l) - dt.date.fromisoformat(k)`. Splitting between the `-` is unnecessary and I don't see why the 0 in front of your 8 would be an issue when using this function. I've also improved upon some aspects of your code (calling `repr()` is not needed, and doing a comparison with `== bool(False)` is redundant in more ways than one)

Comment: it works, the problem now was, that the datetime-format couldnÄt be used for adding or substracting.

Comment: @thom7e But it can be, and that's what I did in my example!

Answer (score 0):

I now did it that way.

```
def get_vacation(list_dates):
    #get the dates of weekends and predefined vacation of a list containing dates
    #input: list of dates
    #outout: list with dates of weekends + vacations
    #indexlist of weekend+vacations
    ind=[index for index,value in enumerate(list_dates) if not np.is_busday(value,busdaycal=bdd)]
    #get listelements with indexlist
    output = [list_dates[i] for i in ind] 
    return output

list_vac=get_vacation(list_alldays)#Feiertage+Wochenende

print(list_vac)
#ich würde jetzt mit datetime64 Format weiterrechnen bei der Subtraktion
#kommt dann timedelta64 Format raus 
delta1=list_vac[5]-list_vac[4]
#print(delta1)
#und als integer
int_delta1=(list_vac[3]-list_vac[2]).astype(int)
print(int_delta1)
```